# Running time explanation of this nested loop

Tags: algorithm, big-o, time-complexity

I'm having trouble understanding the time complexity of this loop:

```
sum = 0;
for(i = 1; i < n; i++)
    for(j = 1; j < i * i; j++)
       if(j % i == 0)
          for(k = 0; k < j; k++)
              sum++;
```

I understand that it takes n^3 time to reach the if statement but I'm having trouble grasping the time complexity of when the if statement is true. I found this explanation online but I still don't understand it. It's not clicking for me. I feel dumb but if someone can break down this problem in even clearer steps I would appreciate it very much!

> Clearly the if statement is reached at most n^3 times. Now consider how often
>   it is true, that is how often does j % i == 0. For each value of i, j ranges from 1 to i^2, and j % i == 0 only when j is a multiple of i. Therefore j % i
>   == 0 only when j = i, 2i, 3i, ..., i^2. Thus the if statement is true i times for each value of i. Thus it is true O(n^2) times. Thus the innermost loop is only reached O(n^2) times. Every time it is reached it iterates j = O(n^2) times. Therefore the total number of operations performed is O(n^4).

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that you go through the problem manually. Like this:

```
i = 1, j = 1, inner loop 1 time. 

i = 2, j = 1, no inner loop. 
i = 2, j = 2, inner loop 2 times
i = 2, j = 3, no inner loop. 
i = 2, j = 4, inner loop 4 times

i = 3, j = 1, no inner loop. 
i = 3, j = 2, no inner loop. 
i = 3, j = 3, inner loop 3 times. 
i = 3, j = 4, no inner loop. 
i = 3, j = 5, no inner loop. 
i = 3, j = 6, inner loop 6 times. 
i = 3, j = 7, no inner loop. 
i = 3, j = 8, no inner loop. 
i = 3, j = 9, inner loop 9 times.
```

and so on. For every i, how often do you execute the inner loop at all, and how often does it get iterated? (How often does the "if" statement get executed - in this case it is less often then the work done for the inner loop iterations, but with different code it would be different so you need to check)? The result you add up for all values i from 1 to n-1.